# face.center returning wrong location

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

I wrote and released an add-on and part of the code finds the center of the faces and uses that for other stuff. A user of my add-on sent me this mesh and running this test code:

```
import bpy
ob = bpy.context.object

for face in ob.data.polygons:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location = face.center * ob.matrix_world)
```

creates the cubes like this:
[image]
They aren't at the right position, doing `face.center * ob.matrix_world` doesn't fix it either.
The weird thing is that if you do **Cursor To Center** and then **Selection To Cursor** and then run the code it works. Any ides why this is?

[.blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/40115)

Comment: Swap the operands - `ob.matrix_world * face.center`? `face.center` is a 3x1 column vector. So this should not work ;). See [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#General_definition_of_the_matrix_product)

Comment: @pinkvertex Perfect, thanks! Mind putting that in an answer?

Comment: maybe the title should be adjusted to reflect the real problem here. (Matrix Vector Multiplication order) -- M*V vs V*M

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18246/47

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of operands is important. See [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#General_definition_of_the_matrix_product).
`face.center` is a 3x1 column vector. So swapping the operands

```
òb.matrix_world * face.center
```

will yield the correct result.