# TypeError: Element-wise multiplication: not supported between 'Matrix' and 'Vector'

Tags: python, scripting, vector, matrix

Blender **2.8** produces the following error  whilst multiplying a combination of matrices and vectors

```
>>> M = Matrix()
>>> v = Vector()
>>> M * v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Element-wise multiplication: not supported between 'Matrix' and 'Vector' types

>>> v * v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Element-wise multiplication: not supported between 'Vector' and 'Vector' types

>>> M * M
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Element-wise multiplication: not supported between 'Matrix' and 'Matrix' types
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Blender 2.8+ Matrix multiplication**

The question code method was in place for Blender <=2.79.9. Blender has since adjusted its `mathutils` module, replacing the asterisk `*` with the at symbol `@`, aka the [PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) binary operator, for multiplying matrices with vectors.

```
>>> M = Matrix()
>>> v = Vector()
>>> M @ v
Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

>>> v @ v
0.0

>>> M @ M
Matrix(((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))
```

Note using `@` will throw the "same type of error"  in <= 2.79.9 Replace with `*` as in question code.

```
>>> M = Matrix()
>>> M @ M
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'Matrix' and 'Matrix'
```