# Blender 2.81 - Moving the origin of multiple selected objects to the median point of their base

Tags: python, origin

There has been a similar question back in 2015 which was answered here:
[Set origin to bottom center of multiple objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42105/set-origin-to-bottom-center-of-multiple-objects)

However time has passed and those scripts no longer seem to be working.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve. I have a scene in Blender with a large amount of tree objects. I want to introduce a few more types of trees into the mix by selecting some of the existing trees and replacing them with Ctrl+L > Link object data. However, because of the irregularity of the terrain they sit on and the difference in scale of these trees, the only reliable way to make sure I dont get floating or sunk trees after replacing is to have the very base of each tree as its origin. Scale after replacement is irrelevant, I can randomize it and it looks good enough.

I'm asking for either a script that can do the above or new ideas on how I could go about replacing these objects. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possibly the only change required re _"However time has passed and those scripts no longer seem to be working.

"_  is https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129473/typeerror-element-wise-multiplication-not-supported-between-matrix-and-vect  See if that seems to be the case.

Comment: Oh wow, that did it! All I had to do was change a SINGLE * to a @ and that made it work again! Can I mark your comment as the answer somehow?

Comment: Good one. Marked as dupe  added other link too, which is strictly speaking not a dupe of this q, but used in conjunction is often the only difference between 2.8x scripts and prior.