# Animation nodes - error

Tags: animation-nodes

I got this error in animation nodes, when i try to sort the ids.

[image]
[image]

my node tree:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, try using the latest version from https://animation-nodes.com/ the error looks like it is using a script designed pre 2.80 when the matrix multiplication has been replaced by @ instead of *. see https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/129473/86891

Comment: looks like mine is the newest version :(

Comment: but...your link helped, i could change my .py file...and the error is gone. Unfortunately...the sorting function still does not work :(

Comment: got it, thank you Gorgious, now it is working fine! Your link helped me a lot! But i had to change it by hand mself in the .py file. The download still seems to have the error inside (mabe just in the mac-version)

Comment: Alright ! If you want the issue to be brought to the attention of the developper, you can open an issue on the official github : https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues share a link to this thread for explanation

Comment: thanks, i opened up an issue.