# VSE Python API : How can I add a new movie strip?

Tags: scripting, video-sequence-editor

I want to use script for fast editing, but everytime I run the script it shows an error in VSE operation part. I have been searching for solution but there is none. Plz help me solve this problem. Thx!

### Script

```
# import
import os, bpy
scene = bpy.context.scene
if not scene.sequence_editor:
    scene.sequence_editor_create()


# rendering settings

render = scene.render
scene.frame_start = 101
scene.frame_end = 3600

render.resolution_x = 1920
render.resolution_y = 1080
render.fps = 60

render.filepath = "C:\\Users\\"
render.image_settings.file_format = 'FFMPEG'
render.image_settings.color_mode = 'RGB'
render.ffmpeg.format = 'MPEG4'
render.ffmpeg.codec = 'H264'

render.ffmpeg.constant_rate_factor = 'HIGH'
render.ffmpeg.ffmpeg_preset = 'REALTIME'

# VSE Operation
scene.sequencer_editor.movie_strip_add(filepath='C:\\Users')



#bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)
```

### System Console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\TEW Demo Script.py", line 28, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'sequencer_editor'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

@Gorgious Thanks you for answering my question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Fix the typo :

It's not `sequencer_editor` but `sequence_editor` (no `r`).

2. You are mixing an operator level ([bpy.ops](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html)) method with an object level method ([SequenceEditor](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SequenceEditor.html#bpy.types.SequenceEditor.sequences)).

The `SequenceEditor` object doesn't have any `movie_strip_add` method. Instead, you have to access its `sequences` attribute and use its `new_movie` method.

When you want to know the members of an object in python, you can use `print(dir(obj))` and it will print out all its attributes.

Example :

```
print(dir(scene.sequence_editor))

>> ['__doc__', '__module__', '__slots__', 'active_strip', 'bl_rna', 'meta_stack', 'overlay_frame', 'proxy_dir', 'proxy_storage', 'rna_type', 'sequences', 'sequences_all', 'show_cache', 'show_cache_composite', 'show_cache_final_out', 'show_cache_preprocessed', 'show_cache_raw', 'show_overlay', 'use_cache_composite', 'use_cache_final', 'use_cache_preprocessed', 'use_cache_raw', 'use_overlay_lock', 'use_prefetch']

print(dir(scene.sequence_editor.sequences))

>> ['__bool__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__doc__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__module__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__slots__', 'bl_rna', 'find', 'foreach_get', 'foreach_set', 'get', 'items', 'keys', 'new_clip', 'new_effect', 'new_image', 'new_mask', 'new_meta', 'new_movie', 'new_scene', 'new_sound', 'remove', 'rna_type', 'values']
```

Now we can call `scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_movie` freely. We just have to pass the required parameters.

To have a list of the method parameters, go in to the python console inside blender and type  `bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_movie(` then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. The different parameters will be printed afterwards :

```
new_movie()
SequencesTopLevel.new_movie(name, filepath, channel, frame_start, fit_method='ORIGINAL')
Add a new movie sequence
```

You can also RTM : [Link to the Docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SequencesTopLevel.html#bpy.types.SequencesTopLevel)

3. TLDR

Replace the last line with

```
scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_movie(
    name="My Awesome Movie Strip", 
    filepath="C://Users//my_awesome_movie.mp4", 
    channel=0,
    frame_start=0)
```

Comment: _I recall it as being  RTFM_

Comment: @batFINGER yeah I considered it but thought it might rub target audience the wrong way ^^ + oops, thought I searched enough for dupe. Oh, well, it was fun :)

Comment: Think of it as a healthy  _"good F"_ which may take away theot need for all that rubbage.   Often also suggest google search akin to _"site:stackoverflow.com python AttributeError"_  for answers to questions regarding generic python errors.

Comment: _btw_ NP re dupe, as answer is answer to question issues, whereas dupe is question goal.  If it was titled re the error, feel it has to be closed as off-topic _"generic python error"_  Often seen is `NoneType has no attribute whatever`   which walks the fine  line, on one hand need to know  blender object references can be `None`  opposed OP having us decipherthe error message for them  ... Perhaps would make a good "catch all" Q & A much like https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129473/typeerror-element-wise-multiplication-not-supported-between-matrix-and-vect/129474#129474  albeit

Comment: error there is generated from `mathutils` a little harder to find info on elsewhere.

Comment: Hey, this is an awesome answer! I love how thorough it is and how well it enables us to use the Python API for ourselves!