# Update export plugin from 2.5 to 2.9 - animated mesh's vertex positions

Tags: python, scripting, export, add-on

I have an old export script that worked in Blender 2.5. Now I wanted to update it to 2.9. My export uses vertex based animation as the MD2 file format uses it, so I need the vertex per animation frame position.

It works, but the mesh is not animated. I only get the vertex positions from the non-animated mesh, repeated for each frame.

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####

bl_info = {
    "name": "GLBasic dda",
    "author": "Gernot Frisch",
    "version": (1,2),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "File > Import/Export > GLBasic dda ",
    "description": "Export GLBasic DDA 3D mesh with animation (.dda format)",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.5/Py/"\
        "Scripts/File_I-O/GLBasic",
    "tracker_url": "https://projects.blender.org/tracker/index.php?"\
        "func=detail&aid=21733&group_id=153&atid=469",
    "category": "Import/Export"
}

# if "bpy" in locals():
#     import importlib
#     if "export_dda" in locals():
#         importlib.reload(export_dda)

import os
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator, TOPBAR_MT_file_export
from bpy.props import BoolProperty, EnumProperty, FloatProperty, \
    FloatVectorProperty, StringProperty
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper


def export_dda(filename, context):

    try:
        file = open(filename, 'w')
    except:
        # error = "IOError #%s: %s" % (errno, strerror)
        # REPORT_DATA['errors'].append("Saving failed - %s." % error)
        # ERROR_MSG = "Couldn't save file!%%t|%s" % error
        print ("Exception during open out file")
        raise

    print ("--------------------\nEXPORT v1.2\n---------------------------\n")
    scene = context.scene
    scene.frame_set(1)
    mesh_obj = context.object
    mesh = mesh_obj.data
    
    mesh.calc_loop_triangles()
    file.write("DDDA 1.1\n")
   
    # (1) UV coordinates for each polygon
    UVCoordinates = None
    for UV in mesh.uv_layers:
        if UV.active_render:
            UVCoordinates = UV.data
            break

    # build uv-dictionary
    tex_list = {}
    tex_count=0
    for uvcoo in UVCoordinates:
        uv_key = (uvcoo.uv[0], uvcoo.uv[1] )
        if not (uv_key in tex_list): # .has_key(tex_key):
            tex_list[ uv_key ]=tex_count
            tex_count=tex_count+1

    file.write("%d # tex count\n" % tex_count)
    file.write("# id u v\n")
    for i in range(0, tex_count):
        for coord in tex_list:
            if tex_list[coord] == i:
                file.write("%.3f %.3f # uv\n" % (coord[0], (1.0-coord[1]) ) )

    # file.write("%d # tex count\n" % len(UVCoordinates))
    # file.write("# id u v\n")
    # for i in range(0, len(UVCoordinates)):
    #     coord = UVCoordinates[i].uv
    #     file.write("%.3f %.3f # uv\n" % (coord[0], (1.0-coord[1]) ) )


    
    # (2) polygon node indices
    file.write("%d # num_faces\n" % (len(mesh.loop_triangles)) )
    file.write("# r g b / npts / id1 id2 id3 ... iduv1 iduv2 ...\n")
    iface=-1
    for face in mesh.loop_triangles:
        iface=iface+1
        vert_in_face = len(face.loops)

        if face.material_index<len(mesh.materials):
            mat = mesh.materials[face.material_index]
            # print "rgb=" ,mat.R, mat.G, mat.B
            file.write("%d %d %d #col\n" % ( (int)(mat.diffuse_color[0]*255), (int)(mat.diffuse_color[1]*255), (int)(mat.diffuse_color[2]*255) ))
        else:
            print ("no material")
            file.write("255 255 255 # no mat color\n")

        file.write("%d   " % vert_in_face) # == 3

        # print("face:")
        # for each vertex of that face
        for i in range (vert_in_face-1, -1, -1): # reverse faces
            # find the x,y,z node index
            vert_index=face.vertices[i]
            # print("node " + str(vert_index))
            file.write("%d " % (vert_index))
            
            # find the uv coord index for that vertex
            if (len(UVCoordinates) > iface):
                u = UVCoordinates[i].uv[0]
                v = UVCoordinates[i].uv[1]
                uvkey = (u, v)
                if not (uvkey in tex_list):
                    file.write("0 ")
                else:
                    file.write("%d " % tex_list[uv_key]);
            else:
                file.write("0 ")

        file.write("\n")


    # (3) per frame vertex coordinates

    """
    #We only have to do this once:
    ob = bpy.context.active_object #getting the object we want.
    dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get() #getting the dependency graph

    #This has to be done every time the object updates:
    ob = ob.evaluated_get(dg) #this gives us the evaluated version of the object. Aka with all modifiers and deformations applied.
    me = ob.to_mesh() #turn it into the mesh data block we want.
    """
    graph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get() #getting the dependency graph

    startFrame = scene.frame_start
    endFrame   = scene.frame_end
    file.write("%d #n keyframes\n" % (endFrame-startFrame+1))
    file.write("# vertices: x y z nx ny nz\n")

    vert_count = len(mesh.vertices);
    for frameIndex in range(startFrame, endFrame+1):
        file.write("# frame %d\n" % frameIndex)
        #update the mesh objects vertex positions for the animation
        #set blender to the correct frame
        scene.frame_set(frameIndex)
        
        mesh_obj.evaluated_get(graph)
        mesh = mesh_obj.to_mesh()
        
        # get the vertices modified by the animation
        # animesh= mesh_obj.create_mesh(scene, True, 'PREVIEW') # FAILS
        # animesh.calc_normals()
        file.write("%d # nvertices, keyframe %d\n" % (vert_count, frameIndex))

        #now for the vertices
        for vert_counter in range(0, vert_count):
            #XYZ
            # vecpos = animesh.vertices[vert_counter].co * mesh_obj.matrix_world.transpose()
            vecpos = mesh.vertices[vert_counter].co #  * mesh_obj.matrix_world.transpose()

            #Normal
            # vecnor = animesh.vertices[vert_counter].normal # * mesh_obj.matrix_world.transpose()
            vecnor = mesh.vertices[vert_counter].normal
            # vecnor = unify_vec3 (mesh_obj.matrix_world.invert().transpose()*vecnor)
            
            new_x=-vecpos[1]
            new_y= vecpos[2] # swap y/z
            new_z=-vecpos[0]
            nor_x= -vecnor[1]
            nor_y=  vecnor[2] # swap y/z
            nor_z= -vecnor[0]

            file.write("%.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f\n" % (new_x, new_y, new_z, nor_x, nor_y, nor_z))

    file.flush()
    file.close()
    print ("done.\n\n")


class ddaExporter(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
    """Save GLBasic 3D model""" # Tooltip
    bl_idname = "export_scene.id_export_dda"
    bl_label = "Export .dda"
    filename_ext = '.dda'

    filepath = StringProperty(name="File Path", description="Filepath used for exporting the dda file", maxlen= 1024, default= "")
    check_existing = BoolProperty(name="Check Existing", description="Check and warn on overwriting existing files", default=True, options={'HIDDEN'})

    def execute(self, context):
        export_dda(str(self.filepath), context)
        return {'FINISHED'}





def menu_func_export(self, context):
    from io_glbasic import export_dda
    import os
    default_path = str(os.path.splitext(bpy.data.filepath)[0] + ".dda")
    self.layout.operator(export_dda.ddaExporter.bl_idname, text='GLBasic dda (.dda)')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ddaExporter)
    TOPBAR_MT_file_export.append(menu_func_export)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ddaExporter)
    TOPBAR_MT_file_export.remove(menu_func_export)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Can you please post the full script? Otherwise hard to test IMHO. The vertices part at the end will also fail. Recommend have a look into: [TypeError: Element-wise multiplication: not supported between 'Matrix' and 'Vector'](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129473/typeerror-element-wise-multiplication-not-supported-between-matrix-and-vect) and https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API

Comment: I changed what I found out, but I still can't get the animated vertex positions. I get the positions of the first frame, repeatedly.

Comment: See [this Q](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146559/how-do-i-get-a-mesh-data-block-with-modifiers-and-shape-keys-applied-in-blender). `mesh_obj.evaluated_get(graph)` returns a new object, it doesn't change `mesh_obj`. So you need to call `to_mesh()` on the object it returns, not on `mesh_obj`. See if that fixes it.

Comment: Yes! That did the trick. Thank you so much!