# This mathutils related code stop working correctly in 2.8

Tags: python, matrix

I ported an old 2.78 addon and was faced with a strange thing, the results in 2.78 and 2.93 are different. In 2.93 the result of the multiplication of matrices is always remaining the same as Matrix.Translation((0, 0, 0)), however in 2.78 it looks like multiplication by zero is simply ignored. How can I mimic the behavior of the 2.78 version?

```
wtm = Matrix.Translation((0, 0, 0))
for bi in reversed(chain):
    b = mod.bones_array[bi]
    wtm *= Matrix.Translation((b.location_x / 100, b.location_z / 100 * -1, b.location_y / 100))
```

[image: Difference in result]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129473/typeerror-element-wise-multiplication-not-supported-between-matrix-and-vect/129474
Looks like 2.80 "*" for vectors was replaced with "@" but 2.93 doesn't see any error with it fro some reason.

Comment: There's no error, because `*` multiplication is supposed to work like Vector multiplication (where each field is multiplied by corresponding field), whereas `@` is proper [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)